# How can I append a new value to a string in such a way that each values are separated by "," except the first one?

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem. I have to iterate on a list of strings and I have to concatenate them into a single string separating these string using the **,** character. The problem is that I need to avoid that this separator is applied before the first string.

I have something like this in my code:

```
let commesse = "";

for(let commessaCorrente of listaCommese) {
    // Append commessaCorrente to commesse string
}
```

I can append in this way:

```
commesse + "," + commessaCorrente;
```

but in this way the **,** will be before the first string. I know that I can use an index and check for example if this is the first word avoiding to append the **,**.

But I want to know if there are some more neat and nice modern way to implement this behavior.

How can I implement it in a smart way?

Comment: You don't. You join your array using `commesse = listaCommese.join(',')` And I don't know what language that is, but either `commesse` has an `s` too many, or `listaCommese` is missing an `s`. Either way, you'll want to fix that. This is also fairly elementary JS, so you probably want to run through https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS just to (re?)familiarise yourself with this language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const phrase = ['You', 'Can', 'Do', 'That', 'Using', 'Join']

console.log(phrase.join(','))
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way i can think of is to use .join() on an array of strings:

```
let commesse = [];

for (let commessaCorrente of listaCommese) {
    commesse.push(commessaCorrente);
}

const commesseString = commesse.join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice` to take a part of the array. Skip 1st element, join the rest with coma. And join all together with `space`

```
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];
const str = [
    fruits.slice(0, 1),
    fruits.slice(1, -1).join(', ')
].join(' ');

console.log(str)
// Banana Orange, Lemon, Apple
```